# Flutter not able to decode json data

Tags: android-studio, flutter, openweathermap

I am currently learning flutter from a udemy course. Following the course now I am building a climate app using openweathermap.org's api. The app was working fine with default location of the emulator but then I followed my instructor and customized the app so that it can use the device current location but the app was not responding and was returning statusCode as 401. I tried running my instructor's code as well but the same problem was there as well so if anyone can tell me the reason of the statusCode being 401 because when I ran the url it gave the correct json data but I think android studio(Flutter) was not able to decode json data.

If someone can please justify the reason for the problem please respond.
Thankyou

Comment: You have to show your code...

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused because of an invalid or bad API key. You can get an API key from the openweathermap.api.

Once it works it will return a 202 status code.